# Req.User values Default to 1st record in DB after Oauth Authentictation Redirect

Tags: node.js, redirect, express, passport.js, sequelize.js

after a successful authentication with Passport.js, I want a redirect to the user's profile page. However, after the redirect, the value of `req.user` is set to the first record of the database. So all users see user /1's profile page, instead of the intended page, let's say /33.

How can I keep the information of the session and `req.user` consistent during a redirect?

The web app is express.js 4.0, and sequelize.js 2.0, and postgres 9.4. Full code is here: https://github.com/skilbjo/dropkey

`routes.js` file

```
// Users ==========================
  app.route('/users/:id([0-9]+)')
    .get(function(req, res) { 
      controller.users.show(req, res, model); 
    });

// Dropbox
  app.route('/auth/dropbox')
    .get( passport.authenticate('dropbox-oauth2') );
  app.route('/auth/dropbox/callback')
  .get(function(req, res) { passport.authenticate('dropbox-oauth2')(req, res, function() {
      res.redirect('/users/' + req.user[0].dataValues.UserId)(req);
    });
  });
```

`passport.js` file

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    return done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.find(id)
    .complete(function(err, user) {
        return done(err, user);
    });
});

// Dropbox
passport.use(new DropboxOAuth2Strategy({
    clientID                : process.env.DROPBOX_KEY,
    clientSecret        : process.env.DROPBOX_SECRET,
    callbackURL         : process.env.DROPBOX_CALLBACK
},
function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    User.findOrCreate({where: { 
        DropboxId: profile.id,
        DropboxToken: accessToken,
        Name: profile.displayName,
        Email: profile.emails[0].value          
    }})
    .complete(function(err, user) {
        if (err) return done(err);
        if (user) {
            return done(null, user);
        } 
    });
}
```

`logs`

```
GET /auth/dropbox 302 3.727 ms - 0
Executing: SELECT "UserId", "DropboxId", "DropboxToken", "Name", "Email" FROM "User" AS "User" WHERE "User"."DropboxId" = // blah blah
[ 
    { dataValues:
      { 
            UserId: 33, // this is correct
            DropboxId: //correct,
            DropboxToken: //correct
        }
    }
]
```

that's all correct... but then on the redirect, even though the endpoint is /33 (not /1), and the information passed as the req.user is for user 1

`logs`

```
GET /auth/dropbox/callback?code=OTsdk-213 302 1266.986 ms - 74
Executing (default): SELECT "UserId", "DropboxId", "DropboxToken", "Name", "Email" FROM "User" AS "User";
[
    { dataValues:
        {
            UserId: 1,  // not the correct user!
            DropboxId: // information for user /1, when I want /33
            DropboxToken: // information for user /1, when I want /33
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend gave me an excellent suggestion: try it on a small app, remove all complexity, and then start building complexity on from that. That way helped to solve the problem here. The issue is to be really careful what you serialize, deserialize, and the general attributes that live in `req.user` and how you use them...

`passport.js`

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user[0].UserId);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(UserId, done) {
    User.find(UserId)
    .complete(function(err, user) {
        return done(err, user);
    });
});
```

`users.js controller`

```
exports.show = function(req, res, model) {  
model.user
.find(req.user.dataValues.UserId) // <<--- this is where I believe the issue was
.then(function(err, user) {
    res.render('users/profile', {
        name    :   req.user.Name,
        email :     req.user.Email
    });
});
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's possible your issue might have something to do with the `serializeUser` function I see in your github:

https://github.com/skilbjo/dropkey/blob/6ef79bbd/lib/config/passport.js#L8

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    return done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.find(id)
    .complete(function(err, user) {
        return done(err, user);
    });
});
```

You're de-serializing from an id, but what you're **serializing** is the user object. You might try serializing like this instead:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    return done(null, user.UserId);
});
```

Another thing that I can't wrap my head around is this code here:

```
passport.authenticate('dropbox-oauth2')(req, res, function() {
    res.redirect('/users/' + req.user[0].dataValues.UserId)(req);
});
```

From what I understand, the express `res.redirect` method returns undefined, so I'm not sure what's going on by calling it like a function the way you are.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. I refactored the serializeUser function to just serialize the UserId. However it still seems after the redirect, the default value of req.user.UserId = 1, not /33 as desired. It seems the show function (shows profile) will only return the first record in the DB.

deserialize { UserId: 2 }

Executing (default): SELECT "UserId", "DropboxId", "DropboxToken", "Name", "Email" FROM "User" AS "User" LIMIT 1;

Comment: Also with this... res.redirect('/users/' + req.user[0].dataValues.UserId)(req);

I was just somehow trying to force the value of req into the show function... since it seems to default to the first record after the redirect.